# warning message whenever I use sudo command

Tags: 18.04, sudo

On a freshly installed ubuntu I get this error message everytime I use sudo command with some other command:

```
$ sudo su -
sudo: unable to resolve host localhost.localdomain: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

any idea what is causing this message and how can I fix it, I have noticed sudo command takes a lot of time also.

Comment: Does `/etc/hosts` contain a `127.0.0.1.  localhost` line? It should.

Comment: @waltinator hosts was was completely empty, so I added that but that does not made any difference. I am still getting that line as message when I use sudo.